# CSS round corners problem

Tags: css, menu, hover, drop-down-menu, state

I have this problem with CSS round corners. The link to example is here: http://www.xplus.dnawrot.nazwa.pl/

As you can see at the top on the **dark blue background** is a dropdown menu. The problem concern hover state on the `first ul li list`(items: *oferta, klienci, akademia*) wchih has children. As you will notice if you make mouse focus on the `oferta` item it display round corners properly, but if you go down to `second ul li` list (drop down - *"rozwiazania branzowe", "produkty", etc*) right side of round corner disapperas. And it's logical becouse there is CSS style for `li` element and `a` element, and if the mouse leaves an `a` element the hover is removed. Does anyone has a solution for this problem?

If the description is not clear let me know and I'll try to explain more detailed.

Regards, 
Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try to wrap "a" and "ul" in a "span" tag and then use css to control **span:hover instead of a:hover**.

```
<li class="">
<span>
<a class="sf-with-ul" title="Klienci" href="http://www.xplus.dnawrot.nazwa.pl/pl/klienci">
<ul style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">
</span>
</li>
```

I haven't tested it but you could give it a try.

Comment: that make sense, I'll try to implement

Comment: hmm... unfortunately xhtml does not validate when I added span tag, so it's not a good idea :|